# Replace Boolean value with name of df column if value is true Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that has Boolean values representing which products each customer owns. How can I replace the Boolean value with the name of the df column if the value is True and change values to null if False?

ex.

input

| Acct Name | product 1 | Product 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| csld solutions | TRUE | FALSE |
| bolo construct | FALSE | TRUE |

output

| Acct Name | product 1 | Product 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| csld solutions | product 1 |  |
| bolo construct |  | Product 2 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`np.where()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) on each column with the help of [`.apply()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) to go through each column.  In [`np.where()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) if x is True, set to `x.name` which contains the column name, if x is False, set to `None`.

```
df.set_index('Acct Name').apply(lambda x: np.where(x, x.name, None)).reset_index()
```

**Result:**

```
        Acct Name  product 1  Product 2
0  csld solutions  product 1       None
1  bolo construct       None  Product 2
```

If you want blank/null string instead of `None`, you can use:

```
df.set_index('Acct Name').apply(lambda x: np.where(x, x.name, '')).reset_index()
```

**Result:**

```
        Acct Name  product 1  Product 2
0  csld solutions  product 1           
1  bolo construct             Product 2
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use the fact that `True` evaluates to `1` and `False` evaluates to `0`, together with string multiplication by `1` returning the string while multiplication by `0` returns the empty string.

Either supply a list of the columns or select them programatically somehow. Below I select all of the `'bool'` columns for which the multiplication will work.

```
# Get all Boolean columns
cols = df.head().select_dtypes('bool').columns

df.loc[:, cols] = df.loc[:, cols].mul(cols)
```

---

```
print(df)
#        Acct Name  product 1  Product 2
#0  csld solutions  product 1           
#1  bolo construct             Product 2
```